# exception message "failed to load media on cast device code 1" while attempting to cast media

Tags: android, google-cast, wowza

When I attempt to cast a video to the ChromeCast Device (CCD) from my Android application, I keep seeing the message below in LogCat.

> failed to load media on cast device, code 1

What does this message mean?

I am also observing some console output on the CCD `http://192.168.1.165:9222` as shown below.

> The page at 'https://www.gstatic.com/eureka/player/player.html?skin' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from '[http://www.demoserver.com:1935/vod/mp4:sample.mp4/manifest.mpd](http://www.demoserver.com:1935/vod/mp4%3asample.mp4/manifest.mpd)' : this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

The message shows up as a warning (yellow triangle with exclamation mark) and not an error (circle with x). I am wondering if this warning on the CCD console correlates with the exception in LogCat?

In words, when in development mode, do I need to also load the mp4 files over HTTPS as well?

To add more information, I am using Wowza. It seems that CORS is enabled by default in Wowza. However, when debugging on the CCD, I see the following request canceled on every retry (Network tab).

> path=[http://www.demoserver.com:1935/vod/mp4:sample.mp4/manifest.mpd](http://www.demoserver.com:1935/vod/mp4%3asample.mp4/manifest.mpd), method=GET, status=(canceled), type=Pending, initiator=media_player.js:52

Does this hint that CORS is really not enabled? When I go to `http://www.demoserver.com:1935/crossdomain.xml` I see the following.

```
<cross-domain-policy>
 <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
 <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
 <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Also note that the media type metadata that I passed in is also changed from `video/mp4` to `application/dash+xml` but this change makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have your media over https but for adaptive streams, you need to have CORS headers, do you have that set up?

That warning message will not cause any error.

Comment: The URL here https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media says, "To implement an encrypted protocol, including DRM, you should develop a Custom Receiver. See DRM support for more information." What does this mean? Does it mean that if I do go HTTPS, that I can no longer use the Styled Media Receiver and must implement a Custom Receiver?

Comment: I am using Wowza, and CORS is enabled by default.

Comment: Encryption is different from https; encryption there means DRM and is different from https. Is your media a simple mp4 or the file you are trying to stream is adaptive stream?

Comment: The media is a simple MP4 file, but I am using Wowza to support cross-platform streaming. So, the MP4 file comes through Wowza, which supports adaptive bit rate (ABR) streaming. When the user is on Android, I specify the RTSP protocol (i.e. `rtsp://www.domain.com:1935/vod/mp4:sample.mp4`) to the VideoView UI component. When the user clicks on the Cast button (in Android), I pass in the HTTP URL (i.e. `http://www.domain.com:1935/vod/mp4:sample.mp4/manifest.mpd`) to the VideoCastManager. Thanks for clarifying HTTPS versus encryption.

Comment: The http url you are referring to is adaptive. The crossdomain.xml is not CORS, that provides a similar functionality for, say, flash players but HTTP CORS is provided through headers. Turn on logging and provide more log info; log should show if CORS is an issue or not. Is that domain you are using recognizable externally?